# Is there a step function with an "in between value" that can be represented by a limit?

Tags: limits, functions, step-function

I would be interested if there is a function $f(x)$ with the property that when a limit on the parameters of the function is be performed you get a step function with an in between value. What I mean by that is, assuming the function depends on a parameter a, you get
$$
\lim_{a\rightarrow \infty} f(x) = \begin{cases}
0\quad x<x_0 \\
c \quad x=x_0 \\
1 \quad x>x_0
\end{cases}
$$
where $x_0$ could be $0$ for example and $0<c<1$.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You mean $f(a,x)$ ? And I'm assuming you are working with pointwise convergence of the limit.

Comment: Yes. For example, the function defined by $f(x) = \begin{cases}
0\quad x<x_0 \\
c \quad x=x_0 \\
1 \quad x>x_0
\end{cases}$ works...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the convergence to be pointwise,

$$
f(a,x) = \begin{cases}
\left(\frac12\sin(x)\right)^a\quad\text{if}\ x<x_0 \\
c-\frac{1}{a} \quad\text{if}\ x=x_0 \\
1+\left(\frac12\sin(x)\right)^a \quad x>x_0
\end{cases}
$$

If you want your function to be **continuous** for each value of $a$, then the question is more interesting. But you didn't mention this in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed I was looking for a continous function for all a but forgot to mention it

Answer (score 0):

With parameter $p\neq 0$
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+(\frac{1}{c}-1)e^{-p^2(x-x_0)}}$$
$f(x\to-\infty)\to 0$

$f(x_0)=c$

$f(x\to\infty)\to 1$

$p\to \infty \qquad 
\begin{cases}
f(x<x_0)\to 0\\
f(x=x_0)=c\\
f(x>x_0)\to 1
\end{cases}$

Comment: Thanks! Thats what I was Lookinge for